# Excel automatic substring replacement

Tags: microsoft-excel

i am looking to create an excel sheet that, when a value is placed in the input column, the output column will automatically replace a list of sub strings found within the input string to a corresponding value. I believe that this requires Vlookup, but i have not been able to get that function to work with substrings. so ive come here looking for aid.

an example table is below showing what im looking for. the Output String column would return the complete input string, with the values found in the Value to Replace Column replaced with those in the Replacement Value column.

| Value to Replace | Replacement Value | Input String | Output String |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Moe | Kirk | Moe and Curly looked down on Larry | Kirk and Spock looked down on Picard |
| Curly | Spock | Larry met with John at Moe's Tavern | Picard met with Riker at Kirk's Tavern |
| Larry | Picard |  |  |
| John | Riker |  |  |

Comment: I think this will need VBA.

Comment: `=REPLACE(C2,FIND(A2,C2),LEN(A2),B2)` will replace ONE of the names in column B (B2 in the example), cannot tell if there is e.g. an `Array formula` that would replace all instances.

Comment: How many replacement values do you expect to have? Based on your example, you could nest 4 `SUBSTITUTE` functions within a formula: `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(C2,$A$2,$B$2),$A$3,$B$3),$A$4,$B$4),$A$5,$B$5)` Not too bad unless you expect to have dozens of values in columns A and B.

Comment: I'm thinking for newer excel `BYROW` with `SUBSTITUTE` will solve it

Comment: @gns, so 365, looks to me you need a recursive `LAMBDA()` - and that taking an array as input.

Comment: @Isolated the hope was to have it expandable, so any value pair i add to column 1 and 2 would affect the output. currently the most i expect to have is 35

Comment: The automated process requires the use of VBAs.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following:

```
=LET(Lookups,  FILTERXML("<group><element>" & SUBSTITUTE(C2," ","</element><element>") & "</element></group>",  "//group/element"),

      TEXTJOIN(" ", TRUE, IFERROR( XLOOKUP(Lookups, A2:A5, B2:B5),Lookups) )
      )
```

It uses the `FILTERXML` trick to divide the input string into words (in this case), then uses `XLOOKUP` to check for each in the "Value to Replace" column. If it finds it, it takes that "Replacement Value" and if it does not, it gives an error. For some reason I'm not researching tonight, using the function's fourth parameter "If Not Found" just changes the error from NA to Value. So it's wrapped with an `IFERROR` to catch those very important errors and replace them with the correct word from `FILTERXML`'s word list. Then `TEXTJOIN` joins the resultant collection of words back into a single string inserting single spaces between them.

It will likely handle what 35 words might throw at it, but it is not particularly robust. Many things one might just type in might confuse the issue. Also, if there is punctuation, it will not handle things correctly as it does not break apart the punctuation from the word it follows (usually follows... sometimes it might, to a human, precede a word...).

But as you experience variety in its inputs, you might adapt it. At least for a bit. At some point it will just not do, as written. Also, the `FILTERXML` word list can only have so many characters (I believe this limit is a bit over 6,000, though maybe the 8,000+ limit applies, maybe. The 32,767 limit definitely does not apply.) before it either errors or cuts the string of characters off at that limit leaving the end of your output defective. Not a problem as shown, but for longer inputs...

Answer (score 0):

If you have the recent Text functions, including `TEXTSPLIT`, the following is more robust as it can handle an input string of any length Excel will accept (32,767 characters) rather than be limited by the shorter string `FILTERXML` is limited to:

```
=TEXTJOIN( " ", TRUE, IFERROR( XLOOKUP( TEXTSPLIT(C2, , " "), A2:A5, B2:B5), TEXTSPLIT(C2,," ")  ))
```

It just splits the input string by the spaces, looks for all of the pieces in the Value to Replace column and either replaces them (if found in that column) with the Replacement Value column entries or keeps the original (if not found in that column) value.

How still not robust:

1. Not accounting for any use of punctuation.
2. Not accounting for phrases which include a space.
3. Not accounting for resulting strings that are longer than Excel's 32,767 character limit for strings.

The last is pretty important. Replace a few thousand "Moe" inputs with "Picard" outputs and even a string near the length limit may well be very over the limit for output.

So, fine with sentences, even crafted oddities. But if the input could be a book length or even a chapter length string, it might have to be broken up into doable pieces of, say, 20-25,000 characters, operated on, and copied back somewhere combining pieces as one does until the chapter/book length input is completely processed. Experience might help with deciding how long an input of your exact material should be to minimize how many pieces have to be processed yet not to "waste a cycle" by ending up with a truncated output string.

Also, a reasonable first approximation for punctuation use might be to make the list of Values to Replace, then use formulas to add to the list a full set of the "bare" list concatenated with reasonably possible punctuation. So a list of 20 items might see 20 more with a period concatenated to them added, 20 more with a comma concatenated, and so on. Naturally, the same would need done to each Replacement Value item. (Or it could be done virtually in the formula though that'd be... harder...) However, your list length doesn't matter at all unlike the string lengths previously mentioned. Your Value to Replace list could 800,000 rows and Excel would not care. Take more time to check? Yes. Care? No.

A first approximation for phrases containing spaces might be to replace the phrasal spaces in the input string with an unusual character, using the same in the Value to Replace and Replacement Value columns, and then change them out with a `SUBSTITUTE` wrapped around the above formula's `XLOOKUP`. (Not its `IFERROR` result... why spend time performing `SUBSTITUTE` on that, eh?) Clunky, but a first approximation.